# Dot on mapView disappears on moving to next tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm trying to display user's current location in a mapVie. I've placed this mapView in a TabViewController among the three I've. Everything works fine. When I move to next tab and come back to this mapView the blue dot disappears but its still shows the correct location. Can anyone help me find where I'm going wrong. Below is the image before and after I move to next tab.[image: Initial View appearance] [image: View after moving to another tab]

Below is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
[ self.mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
 _mapView.userTrackingMode=YES;
}

   -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
 {

CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 1000, 1000);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: By the way, userTrackingMode is not a BOOL -- it's an enum with three possible values.  Check the documentation.

Comment: @Anna thank you I'll check on it..;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your operation in **-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated**

Comment: Thanks a lot that did it…I didn't know why i didn't see this silly mistake…;)